# extremely slow CSS3 box-shadows in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css

I've been developing an app specifically for modern browsers and have made very heavy use of the box-shadow property.

Until recently this has been absolutely fine on all supporting browsers.  However about a month ago when testing in Chrome I noticed that scrolling was 'extremely' slow, to the point of being almost unusable.

Over the past month I have tried ripping out scripts/messing with my html structure, everything you can think of until finally today I have found the cause.

With box-shadow / webkit-box-shadow disabled on all elements that I had it set for, the problem disappears.

What strikes me as odd is that it worked fine in Chrome until around a month ago.  Incidentally the scrolling on the windows version of safari is fine, albeit a little slower than IE/Opera and Firefox.

Is this a known problem? Does anyone have a workaround for this?

And most importantly, is there another method of replicating the same effect without using the CSS3 property?

Comment: I can't speak to the specific problem, but CSS3 effects are known and documented to slow down page rendering.

Regarding replicating the effect, could you give us a sample of how you're using the shadow so we can help you find an answer?

Comment: Indeed, it just seems so odd that it was okay until recently, without any new box shadows being added.  Regardless.  I am using it simply to add minor shadows around elements in order to give a 3D effect.  I am not using the effect to simulate something it wasn't designed for.  Most usage is between 4px-10px radius around the edge.  The only difficulty is that this 'container elements are dynamic in size as content can be added/removed.  Strangely enough it is only scrolling that has the issue, all other repaints/reflows appear fine

Comment: Yah, even more interesting is this thread from a year ago RE: safari: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789853/css3-box-shadow-causes-scroll-lag-slow-performance-on-safari-5-0-2   One thing I remember is that both the radius of the shadow, and the number of shadows, slows it down. Sorry I don't have a fix, though.

Comment: Yep, I saw that while researching the problem.  Perhapsit was fixed in safari yet the bug remains in chrome?  Or perhaps they reintroduced it recently.  I've been reading about the new border-image property.  Perhaps there is a solution there?

Comment: My website experiences the same thing when I have a lots of box-shadow, and the scrolling in chrome on Mac is terrible recently.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There was a bug report opened and closed in Webkit last year:

[CSS3 box-shadow causes scroll-lag (slow performance) on Safari 5.0.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789853/css3-box-shadow-causes-scroll-lag-slow-performance-on-safari-5-0-2)

It seems Chrome has an open bug on an older version:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=95164

Airbnb discussed the problem recently, and actually changed their final design because of it:

http://nerds.airbnb.com/box-shadows-are-expensive-to-paint

There's a group of people recently gaining an interest in programmatically testing CSS performance. Here's a bookmarklet you can use to start your own testing:

http://andy.edinborough.org/CSS-Stress-Testing-and-Performance-Profiling

In the meantime, you're right that hacking border-image is an option. Check it out here:

[Scroll Lag with CSS3 box-shadow property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249619/scroll-lag-with-css3-box-shadow-property)

Comment: Great links, huge thanks Matt... I guess its not just me then! I'm going to have a play with the border-image property over the next hour and see if I can come up with something usable.  Thanks!

Comment: it turns out using the border-image property was quite simple and has solved the problem perfectly.  That last link you posted did the trick.  Obviously I modified the image/css to match my site, added rounded corners and gradients and have been able to replace the CSS gradients also in what is quite an elegant solution.  This has had the byproduct of reducing my CSS size dramatically since I don't have to have so many lines supporting each browser in terms of gradients/box-shadows/border-radius.  Cheers!

Comment: I used `box-shadow` in my buttons of my phone app and it lagged before `:active` with a delay still, sure it's a new bug.

Comment: 2015 and the lag continues in chrome! Terrible! I don't care how fast (or slow) my PC is! If Firefox is smooth and ... wait for it ... .... Internet Explorer... then chrome has NO excuse!! Google are obviously paying more attention their ADS than making their browser user friendly (something they always bang on about)

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the box-shadow particularly, maybe something else in your app just consumes way too much resource and box-shadow just happens to be the cherry on top.

Nevertheless, I can confirm that box-shadow on overly long or large elements causes performance issues. I work for a certain drag'n'drop form builder and tried setting box-shadow on a 900px x 1000px div and the scrolling started lagging up immediately. Ours is a very ajax heavy web-app, so others might afford to get better results, but still, I think this is a valid example.

So I went old-school and created images instead. I think the most proper way to get image-box shadows working without too much image load is to have an element with a fixed width.

What I did was three image slices. One slice from top to just beneath top corners, one from the bottom to just above the bottom corners and one thin slice from the middle which I used on a div as background image with a repeat-y so that I can dynamically change to divs height fit the users page.

You can slice even more to fit any box but it becomes too much(at least 5 extra images and 8 extra divs to be precise) for a box-shadow imo.

Comment: Like yours, my app is a single page, resource heavy highly ajax driven app involving lots of drag/drop and visual effects.  Unfortunately on all of the elements I don't have the luxury of fixed widths, though this will certainly fix a fair few of them.  Your solution sounds a good one but i'm going to leave the question open for another hour or so in the hope that someone else comes up with another alternative.  Many thanks!

Comment: please do, I would love to see if someone can come up with something better. I'm not very fond of this either but sometimes you do what you gotta do :)