# Why does transitioning the box shadow cause a full page repaint?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, google-chrome-devtools

I noticed that my page was lagging when I hovered over an element with an animated `box-shadow`. Using Chrome's Devtools, I noticed that the entire page was being repainted when I hovered over the element. The repaint was taking 40+ milliseconds, or about 3 frames. The `transition` lasts about half a second, so there's noticeable lag during the half second.

How do I limit the repaint to just the area with the box shadow?

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8sa41xfL/

```css
html,body{
    height:100%;
}

#test{
    background:red;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    transition:box-shadow 0.5s;
}

#test:hover{
    box-shadow:0 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id=test></div>
```

`transform:translateZ(0)` doesn't work on my page, but it works in the fiddle. Is there another fix aside from `transform:translateZ(0)`?

Comment: Not seeing the repaint/lag in Iceweasel (Firefox).

Comment: I see the repaint in both JSFiddle and the inline snippet on Chrome, might just be a Chrome bug.

Comment: @BlagoEreš: Yes it does (on Chrome). Activate the "Show Paint Rect" option from Chrome Dev tools and have a look at the area that gets repainted everytime. You would most likely see a red/green blinking rectangle (depending on Chrome version).

Comment: It does not repaints the whole page in chrome now, (version 64)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the thread linked in Pierre's answer `box-shadow` are expensive to paint. Explaining why it is expensive would require in-depth understanding of the way rendering works and I don't have near enough knowledge to explain it completely. But this answer attempts to explain why the whole page gets repainted and the various possible methods to avoid it.

---

**According to [CSS Triggers website](http://csstriggers.com/#box-shadow):**

> Changing box-shadow does not trigger any geometry changes, which is good. But since it is a visual property, it will **cause painting** to occur. Painting is typically a **super expensive operation**, so you should be cautious.
>
> Once any pixels have been painted the page will be composited together.

---

**Why does the whole page get repainted everytime?**

The below articles explain the way that painting actually works at a high level:

- [HTML5 Rocks - How Browsers Work - Painting](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Painting)
- [The Chromium Project - GPU accelerated rendering in Chrome](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome)

Based on those articles, we can see that each node in the DOM tree that produces a visual output is considered as a RenderObject and that each RenderObject is part of a RenderLayer directly or indirectly. Whenever a change happens, the renderer (or the render object) invalidates its rectangle (or RenderLayer) on screen and triggers a repaint.

In this case it seems like the whole page is getting repainted because the `#test` element does not warrant the creation of a separate RenderLayer (based on the criteria mentioned in the Chromium Project article) and so becomes a part of the root render layer. Because it is a part of the root render layer the whole page is getting repainted everytime a repaint is required.

The **following snippet proves that the above assertion is correct**. Here, I have added a `#cover` element (with positioning) to enclose the `#test` element. Now since the `#cover` element has explicit positioning, it creates an extra layer above root layer and `#test` becomes a part of this intermediate layer. Now, we can see that the `box-shadow` transition repaints only this intermediate layer and not the whole page.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#cover {
  position: relative;
}
#test {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}
#test:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id=cover>
  <div id=test></div>
</div>
```

---

**What is the solution?**

There are various CSS properties that can be used to address this problem but they all seem to point to the same point at a high level - which is, to create a separate render layer for the `#test` element.

Below are a few possible options to create a separate render layer for the `#test` element:

- By adding explicit position properties - This is the same option described in Pierre's answer but `absolute` positioning is not the only option. Even `relative` positioning would solve it.

  ```css
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  #test {
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
  }
  #test:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id=test></div>
  ```
- By adding transparency (opacity) - Browsers seem to treat even `opacity: 0.99` as adding transparency and it is very useful because adding this doesn't cause any visual difference.

  ```css
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  #test {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    opacity: 0.99;
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
  }
  #test:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id=test></div>
  ```
- By adding a dummy CSS filter - We could add a `filter: blur(0px)` as it would do nothing.

  ```css
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  #test {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px);
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
  }
  #test:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id=test></div>
  ```

Answer (score 6):

CSS box shadows are expensive to paint. Read more on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8993972/1029952).

If you want to avoid a full page repaint, use a `position:absolute` on your element. This will repaint the area that surrounds your element without affecting the whole page. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8sa41xfL/1/).