# Box-shadow very slow scrolling (particularly - opera)

Tags: scroll, opera, css, lag

I'm writing first time on this website, because I have big problem with css3 exactly box-shadow, so I start from the beginning  :)
I made website and it worked good until I changed all graphic. 
I did box-shadow and now my website works very slow (exactly scrolling).
It is address: skuterpl.vot.pl (version with new graphic and box-shadow)
strona.pzs1.pl (Old version with old graphic and without box-shadow, this website works very good).
I'm asking you for help me with this problem.

Comment: http://skuterpl.vot.pl scrolls just fine for me in Firefox 10. You might want to reduce the `radius` for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a very large shadow radius, it can affect performance - there's a post here about it affecting webkit browsers [CSS3 box-shadow causes scroll-lag (slow performance) on Safari 5.0.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789853/css3-box-shadow-causes-scroll-lag-slow-performance-on-safari-5-0-2) , though I believe now fixed.

Lowering the amount of box-radius blur should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

things you should take notice of certain factors that can slow down a page:

- heavy graphics (like huge backgrounds)
- a fixed background
- element opacity / image transparency
- animated images
- text/box shadows
- constantly running scripts/event firing (like scrolling events)

although the old page works, i can still see some things that need optimization.

Comment: Graphic is good, because if I turn off all box-shadow, website works good, so the problem is box-shadow and it need some fix.